# Ethernet to UART (or RS232) conversion

Tags: microcontroller, uart, ethernet, converter, rs232

For the PCB I'm designing, I need serial communication (1.8V UART, 3.3V UART, 5V UART or RS232, whichever is easiest) from an Ethernet connection (the devices connected to the Ethernet network will preferably send data/receive directly over Ethernet, so no need for the opposite conversion).

The question is how best to convert from Ethernet to UART or RS232?

In total, I expect I will need 6 serial communications. The devices on the other end are outside of my control, so I need to have some way to configure baud-rate, parity bit, stop bit. This configuration can be done either through the same Ethernet connection, or trough any usual lower level way (uart, i2c, SPI, CAN, GPIOs, ...).

I would like to be able to use baud rates as high as 115200 baud (1M is even better) on each output (but I can accept that not all 6 channels have this baudrate at the same time : let's say a minimum total baudrate of 300 000 baud).

For now, he ideas I have :

- using a high end MCU/MPU with ehternet port and 6 UARTs : I think for one UART it will be enough. But I'm unsure about handling 6 serial communications at the same time (particularly at higher baud rates). If I need 6 MCUs, it will start to be quite complex (and use a lot of PCB space). If a single MCU is enough, then this is probably a good solution (if I have about 20% free ressources, I can also use it for other stuff needing a microcontroler, so nearly no extra cost)
- using a FPGA with ethernet port : more likely to be able to manage 6 uarts simultanously, but more complex to do than on a MCU (and I have less experience in FPGAs than in MCUs)
- some "direct" way to convert an ethernet connexion to a single UART or RS232 : I found a few modules, but nothing for PCB mount.

Do you think the MCU approach is viable (with for example a 500MHZ STM32 with ethernet port)?

If so, is there a simpler approach? Or if the MCU route won't work, what alternative route could I try?

NB : I'm aiming at reducing PCB space and development time far more than reducing components costs (very small series)

Feel free to ask if you need any additional information

Comment: There are embeddable serial device servers from Moxa, but nothing with multiple uarts as far as I've seen.

Comment: There are also board level solutions from Wiznet, Lantronix, TI and others. What are the bandwidth requirements from the serial ports? is it 6 x 900Kbps or 6x9600bps? A 500MHz MCU can do the former easily.

Comment: @Arsenal : 1 ethernet to 1 serial is fine to me as long as the devices are not excessively big (I will integrate an ethernet switch anyway, I will just need a few more ports). I will have a look at the moxa devices (I knew they did serial over ethernet as big modules, but I didn't new they also did ethernet to serial for PCB mount.

Comment: @LiorBilia : do you mean that 6 x 900Kbps is fine on a 500MHz MCU? If so, that's more than enough for me. 6 x 115Kbps would be nice. 3 x 115Kbps + 3 x 9600bps is acceptable.

Comment: These boxes already exist. Why do you must design your own?

Comment: @Justme : we currently use a boxed module. However, for the next revision of our electronics, I would like to go down to a single PCB instead of half a dozen, in order to simplify wiring and maintenance (currently, most external connectors have to go to 2 or 3 different PCBs). So I would like to integrate it on my own PCB so that I can mix it with other features (power supply, management of which serial port can be active, adding other signals to the same connector, ...). What's more, I'm already planing an ethernet switch on the PCB, so adding 2 ethernet connectors is quite space consuming)

Comment: @Arsenal : Moxa seems indeed to have a quite compact module for PCB mount ( https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/serial-device-servers/serial-embedded-modules/miineport-e2-series ) which will serve I think. Just the key components to integrate them directly on my PCB would be perfect.

Comment: I'll just leave this here, for no particular reason because shopping suggestions on this site are totally illegal: Digi makes such devices. https://www.digi.com/products/networking/infrastructure-management/serial-connectivity

Comment: [TIDM-TM4C129XS2E RTOS-Based Configurable Serial-to-Ethernet Converter on High Performance MCUs Reference Design](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-TM4C129XS2E) is an example reference design from TI, which might serve as a starting point if you want to create a custom MCU based solution.